Discrete ADC LDO placement on ADC
I am making a design that includes discrete ADC. I use an LDO to feed the ADC. I also feed the LDO with SMPS. Why did I use LDO before ADC? Because I want to suppress the ripple. That's why I used an LDO that will suppress the switching frequency of the SMPS before the ADC, as in the analog devices and TI documentation. (Even though the ADC has a high PSRR, I am measuring at the uVolt level, so I do not want to see any switching noise around the ADC).
My question here is, is it better to move LDO closer to ADC or keep it closer to SMPS? If we think of it with the logic of finding and eliminating the noise at its source, having the ldo close to the SMPS seems like a better option. So, as I showed in the image, is it better to move the ldo closer to the a or b direction? Any ideas?


Hi,
I would place it closer to the ADC. In terms of noise rejection, then having the LDO closer to the ADC, it can filter out more noise after it leaves the SMPS before it reaches the ADC.

LDOs have a "reference input" pin, which is often called "ground". The internal voltage reference and thus the output voltage are referenced to this pin.
If the LDO's "ground" pin is placed on a noisy ground (like next to a switching regulator) then the LDO will attempt to reproduce whatever noise comes into "ground" into its output.
Likewise, the LDO's output cap creates a HF short circuit between its "ground" and "VCC" sides.
So if you put the LDO in a place where the ground is noisy, you'll get the same noise in the output. Thus it is better to put it at the point of load, next to the ADC. If the ADC has a "negative reference input" (doesn't matter if it is called something else like "ground") then putting the LDO and output cap next to it is optimum.
The LDO's input cap, which needs to be next to the LDO for stability, will inject noise into ground too. That's a good occasion to put a resistor or ferrite bead in series with the supply from the SMPS to avoid this, and it also gives better HF PSRR.
Note LDO datasheet PSRR is specified at a certain dropout voltage. If dropout is too low in your application due to input voltage being too low, then the PSRR degrades significantly because the pass transistor doesn't have enough headroom to operate. So if you pick a LDO with sexy datasheet PSRR curves at a dropout of 1V, you will get what the datasheet says for a dropout of 1V or more, but if you operate it with a dropout of 0.3V, who knows what you will get.
If your ADC draws varying current from the analog supply or reference, then the LDO's transient response to that current variation also matters. Any "low noise" voltage from which a varying current is drawn may no longer be "low noise".

I understood the approach of polluting the GND, the perspective is very good,maybe this might seem too overthingking and specific  my perspective and concern is that the SMPS power plane gets close to the ADC and pollutes the ADC around it through coupling.

If you do a good placement on the switching converter with tight loops then you'll minimize ground pollution. Is it a buck converter?

yes its a buck conv

If you group the input cap GND and lower mosfet (or buck chip) GND together and connect to GND plane with the same vias then input current of your buck (which is a square wave) will not go through the ground plane. This nasty current only circulates in the loop between input cap and 2 MOSFETs. If you manage to put GND for the output cap as close as possible then the sawtooth inductor current is also kept as much as possible away from the ground plane.
